# How to insert only one row per hour from Excel into a SQL Server table by using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have 60k rows in an Excel spreadsheet, how to insert one row per hour into a SQL Server table using a SSIS package?

Please help me. TIA

Comment: Do you really want to insert one row per hour (this would take 60k hours) or are you looking for some kind of aggregation algorithm? If this is the case, could you please provide some more details and some sample data?

Comment: I have one sales requirement to import one row per hour to the table from excel using SSIS package. @werner

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing this, but...

Create your control flow in two pieces: one to insert a row of data, and one to wait.  Loop the wait task back to the insert task.  (You'll probably want some way to exit the loop.)

The insert could be a single-row data flow or an explicit Execute SQL Task.

Two ways to do the wait task:

- If you don't mind remaining connected to the database, add an "Execute SQL Task" into your control flow and have it execute the SQL command "WAITFOR '01:00:00';" then create a loop from the Execute SQL Task back to your insert control task.  Presumably you have some way to exit the loop...
- If you don't want to remain connected to the database, you can do the same thing by writing a Script Task, but that takes writing a little C# if that doesn't scare you.  Use it the same as the Execute Script Task.

Good luck.